# Get the selected dropdown related value into the text box

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to generate the salary after user selects the designation dropdown value from the database.
[image]

my db strucuture is as follows:

```
employee:
 emp_id   dep_id  
   1        1
   2        1


designation:
 dep_id     des_name     salary
   1       accountant    20000
```

This is my html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="initial">Designation :</label>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <select class="form-control input-sm" name="classification" id="classification" onchange="changeValue();"> 

                <?php while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)):; ?>
                <option><?php echo $row3[2]; ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

            </select>
            <span class="error_form" id="classification_error_message"></span>
        </div>
    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="basicSalary">Basic Salary :</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="basicSalary" id="basicSalary" placeholder="0.00">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's easy enough to do with javascript but the question lacks any detail of the HTML

Comment: i add my html code

Comment: what does the `changeValue` function do?

Comment: sir,it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using this code butt this code from php codeigniter. Now u can changing it according to your requirements.

```
    <div class="item form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">select Categories <span class="required">*</span>
              </label>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

   <select class="form-control" name="cat" id="catogires">
<!-- <option  value="">Select categories</option>-->
            <?php 
               $data=$this->Product_Model->cat_select();

            foreach($data as $row)
            { ?>
                <option <?php if ($product->cat_id==$row->cat_id) echo "selected='selected'"; ?> value="<?php echo $row->cat_id?>"><?php echo $row->cat_name;?></option>
         <?php

           }
            ?>

            </select>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Uhm. What is this mess? Doesn't answer the question, not even close. Wheres the javascript to control the behaviors? Wheres the setup of array values? This is junk ripped from some framework, and missing multiple things that makes it even close to functional as is.